# Can we Provide a file pattern as input in pandas read_csv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

My filename is Manu_Nwrk_Dump-2019_7_15-11_2_58_99.csv where the text after Dump is date and other junk numbers (not fixed).
Is it possible to provide a file pattern as Manu_Nwrk_Dump*.csv in pandas read_csv input

Tried passing Manu_Nwrk_Dump*.csv which didnt work

Comment: I guess you want to read all the dump files one by one - here's what i would have done. Use os.walk to read all file paths , keep a main dataframe , while opening each file , concat the file  to the main dataframe. If this is what you want then tell me, i write you a sample code.

Comment: Thanks Madhur. I used glob and it worked

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved by using glob.

```
from glob import glob
for f in glob('Manu_Nwrk_Dump*.csv'):
    my_data = pd.read_csv(f,sep='\t', index_col=False)
```